# Celestial Warlock's Radiant Soul: are there any radiant or fire spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

So my Celestial Warlock just hit level 6 and gained the Radiant Soul feature:

> Starting at 6th level, your link to the Celestial allows you to serve as a conduit for radiant energy. You have resistance to radiant damage, and **when you cast a spell that deals radiant or fire damage**, you add your Charisma modifier to one radiant or fire damage roll of that spell against one of its targets.

I'm having trouble finding Warlock spells that do Fire or Radiant damage, though. *Hellish Rebuke* (which doesn't really mesh well with the Celestial theme) on the Warlock spell list (PHB) and *Guiding Bolt*, *Flaming Sphere* and *Flame Strike* from the expanded spell list.

Am I missing something, or is this ability just not terribly useful? Does this ability come online later, with *Mystic Arcanum*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### There are 18, 9 of them are not in the PHB, and 3 are available only through Pact of the Tome.

[This DnDBeyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/class/warlock?filter-search=&filter-damage-type=51&filter-damage-type=58&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=) shows several on the Warlock spell list:

- [*Create bonfire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-bonfire) (cantrip, *XGtE*)
- [*Green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) (cantrip, *SCAG* & *TCoE*)
- [*Hellish rebuke*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hellish-rebuke) (1st level, *PHB*)
- [*Spirit shroud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-shroud) (3rd level, *TCoE*)
- [*Elemental bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-bane) (4th level, *XGtE*)
- [*Sickening radiance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sickening-radiance) (4th level, *XGtE*)
- [*Wall of light*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-light) (5th level, *XGtE*)
- [*Investiture of flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/investiture-of-flame) (6th level, *XGtE*)
- [*Crown of stars*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/crown-of-stars) (7th level, *XGtE*)

And on the [Celestial Warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheCelestial)'s expanded list:

- [*Sacred flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sacred-flame) (cantrip, *PHB*)
- [*Guiding bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guiding-bolt) (1st level, *PHB*)
- [*Flaming sphere*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flaming-sphere) (2nd level, *PHB*)
- [*Wall of fire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) (4th level, *PHB*)
- [*Guardian of faith*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guardian-of-faith) (4th level, *PHB*)
- [*Flame strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flame-strike) (5th level, *PHB*)

Notably, *there is only one spell on the generic warlock spell list in the Player's Handbook*. Eight more spells are added in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*.

Available only through Pact of the Tome:

- [*Fire bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt) (cantrip, *PHB*)
- [*Produce flame*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/produce-flame) (cantrip, *PHB*)
- [*Word of radiance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/word-of-radiance) (cantrip, *XGtE*)

Comment: seems to me like it's a minor buff to level 1+ spells, and it makes cantrips a little better if you for some reason can't / won't use Eldritch Blast, for example if your target has cover (-> sacred flame).

Comment: @PixelMaster my celestial warlock (currently level 8 and waiting for the campaign to resume when the DM recovers from a RL inflicted delay) has found it to be exaclty that: a modest boost and situationally useful.

Comment: @PixelMaster Or if you're fighting zombies/other undead who happen to be weak to radiant damage.

Comment: Well, I definitely love the nonspecific timing of "When you cast a spell that X" :(

Comment: @Medix2 I decided to roll it back and not make that judgment in this answer.